# Selector on RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

I know there are a lot of subjects about this and i read all of them. But still I couldn't make that selector working on RelativeLayout.

So i need your help. Here is my code.

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_background" />
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/calendarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarItem1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/selector_dashboard_calendar_icon"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:lines="2"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I made child views not clickable and not focusable, all parent layouts except the one that i put selector has after descendent focusability. What happens is background only changes only when the layout is clicked but i want it to be changed on the selected state.